# Zero Exit Rate Calculation Issue for Internal Shop Search in GA4 using GTM

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager, google-analytics-4

I'm currently using with Google Analytics 4 (GA4) and I'm trying to calculate the exit rate on the zero search results page within the internal shop search. I've set up the measurement using GTM (Google Tag Manager) to track the relevant data. While I can see the page views for the zero search results page and the search terms that led to them, I'm only seeing zeros for the exits. This discrepancy is posing a challenge for me.

[Screenshot of Exit Rate Analysis](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0JNXA.png)

In an attempt to solve this problem, I defined the dimensions for the search term and included the metrics for event count and exits. I also set up a filter with the following criteria: the event name must contain "view_search_results_zeroresults". This filter ensures that only events related to the zero search results page are displayed.

**I configured the tag as follows in GTM:**

[Screenshot of the configuration of the tag](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JjGVs.png)

Tag Type: Google Analytics: GA4 Event

Configuration Tag: GA4-Tag

Event Name: view_search_results_zeroresults

Event Parameters:

Parameter Name: search_term

Value: {(Search Parameter)}

**Furthermore, I configured the trigger as follows:**

[Screenshot of the configuration of the trigger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/449D7.png)

Trigger Type: Page View - Window Loaded

Cookie-Analysis: equals 1

Search_Array: matches RegEx ^$

Pagetype: equals searchresults

Reference to this trigger: GA4 - Tag (The tag described from above)

However, despite my best efforts, I'm still seeing zeros for the exit rate.